# How to apply Java generics to simplify this code

Tags: java, generics, code-cleanup

I would to learn if there is a way to avoid the casting in the second line of the code snippet below.

Also, is there a way to further simply the code by using generics for convertToInteger, convertToBoolean etc in addIfMatters method?

```
public void process() {
    // How can I avoid the cast below?
    Boolean value = (Boolean) addIfMatters(target, source, true);  
    if (value){
        // I have some stuff to do here
    }
}

private Object addIfMatters(Map<String, Object> target, Source source, Object defaultValue) {
    Object value = null;
    if (needed(source)) {
    if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) {
        value = convertToBoolean(source.getValue, defaultValue); // returns 'defaultValue' if value in source is null
    } else if (defaultValue instanceof Integer) {
        value = convertToInteger(source.getValue, defaultValue);
    } else if...
        // so on
    }
    target.put(source.getKey(), value);
}
```

Comment: You could make the `addIfMatters` method generic (see MadProgrammer's answer). But you still have the many decision cases (if - else if - else if - ...). For a real generic method you must also get rid of that, and that means to also write _one_ generic `convert` method. For this, you must tell us how the `Source` class looks like (i.e. what is `source.getValue`?).

Comment: source.getValue() returns Object (they are generally int, boolean, float or String.

Comment: Another problem: What are the `convert` methods doing? This is the main problem ...

Comment: Why not simply overload the method? It looks like every overload would be different as to justify them and they would be type safe. Plus, given your conversions, it seems the number of overloads is reasonably limited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could, basically, set up the `addIfMatters` method to return the same type as the `defaultValue`, for example...

```
public void process() {
    Map<String, Object> target = null;
    Source source = null;
    Boolean value = addIfMatters(target, source, true);  // How can I avoid the cast on this line?
    if (value) {
        // I have some stuff to do here
    }
}

private <T> T addIfMatters(Map<String, Object> target, Source source, T defaultValue) {
    T value = null;
    if (needed(source)) {
        if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) {
            value = convertToBoolean(source.getValue, defaultValue); // returns 'defaultValue' if value in source is null
        } else if (defaultValue instanceof Integer) {
            value = convertToInteger(source.getValue, defaultValue);
        }
}
    return value;
}
```

**Updated**

There is a significant lack of context which makes trying to provide a suitable solution very difficult...

For example, if `Source` could be applied to use a generic type, then there would be no need for the conversion methods and it would ensure that there was a connection between the `source`'s value and the default value been applied, for example...

```
public void process() {
    Map<String, Object> target = null;
    Source<Boolean> source = null;
    Boolean value = addIfMatters(target, source, true);  // How can I avoid the cast on this line?
    if (value) {
        // I have some stuff to do here
    }
}

private <T> T addIfMatters(Map<String, Object> target, Source<T> source, T defaultValue) {
    T value = null;
    if (needed(source)) {
        value = source.getValue();
        if (value == null) {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
}
    return value;
}    

public boolean needed(Source source) {
    return true;
}

public class Source<T> {
    public T getValue() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this compile? Doesn't it need an (unchecked) cast when you assign to `value`?

Comment: The `convertToBoolean` and `convertToInteger` are going to make things messy...and yes, for the most part, it compiles...

Comment: Any suggestions for achieving what convertToBoolean/convertToInteger are doing, in a cleaner way?

Comment: I ended up with `private <T> T convertToBoolean(Object value, T defaultValue) {`, but that's not really a clean solution...

Comment: @greppz from the moment you need to use `instanceof` you cannot expect to have very clean code...

Comment: You could also use `value = (T)convertToBoolean(source.getValue(), (Boolean)defaultValue);` which is not very clean either, but the use of `instanceof` has at least narrowed `T` to a type of `Boolean`, which makes the casting safer

Comment: Wondering if there a way to get rid of instanceof as well?

Comment: @greppz you should provide more info about the real problem, then we could provide a better design and solution.

Comment: It would depend on what the convert methods are trying to do and what `getSource` is returning...

Comment: I have an option to make source.getValue return String ("true", "false", "1", "10.12", "foo" etc).  Convert methods are converting them to a first class object from String value.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'd like to tear my eyes out :P

Comment: @greppz Seriously going to need more context, may be a running example with test data would help...

Comment: @greppz I wonder how do you get the data stored as `String`s to begin with. This now seems more like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Edit your question properly and provide the necessary data to understand the real problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it is coming from a legacy API.

Comment: @MadProgrammer accepting your answer as it has given me sufficient pointers to improve my code.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know this to be a boolean at compile-time, the easiest way would be to make multiple wrappers, one for each type.

```
private boolean addBooleanIfMatters(Map<String, Object> target, Source source, boolean defaultValue){
    return (Boolean) addIfMatters(target, source, defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet to implement Generics.

```
private <T> T addIfMatters(Map<String, Object> target, Source source, T defaultValue) {
        T value = null;
        if (needed(source)) {
            if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) {
                value = convertToBoolean(source.getValue(), defaultValue); // returns 'defaultValue' if value in source is null
            } else if (defaultValue instanceof Integer) {
                value = convertToInteger(source.getValue(), defaultValue);
            } else  {

            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: That will make a unchecked type warning when you cast to `T` in the last line.

Comment: I would not recommend doing the cast to (T).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes. Thx for your input. I have modified the code.

Comment: Will this compile? Doesn't it need an (unchecked) cast when you assign to value?

Comment: Please test the code before posting it. If you don't have an IDE at hand atm, use http://ideone.com

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have removed the casting from this method and moved into individual convert method. We need to do at-least one place to achieve this. Without Casting we cant do method generics. Even you like or not this is language dependency. You should accept and follow this.

Comment: I should not accept it, OP has. Also, after your edit, the code seems very similar to MadProgrammer's answer which is dealing with the problem. I would need more data to understand why to have this odd design and I would probably rewrite the entire code to avoid this bad design.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, the best option would be to do what MadProgrammer suggested and make Source generic. Otherwise, I would do it like the below. This is assuming that the convertBoolean etc does not do anything except return defaultValue or convert the given value.

```
public <T> T addIfMatters(Map<String, Object> target, Source source, T defaultValue) {
    if (needed(source)) {
        Object o = source.getValue();
        if(o == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        Class<?> targetClass = defaultValue.getClass();
        if(targetClass.isInstance(o)) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T value = (T) o;
            return value;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Types do not match");
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to generically convert a string to an arbitrary type in Java. So use overloading where code needs to be different for different types, and generics where code is essentially the same:

```
public void process() {
    Boolean value = addIfMatters(target, source, true);
    if (value){
        // I have some stuff to do here
    }
}

private Boolean addIfMatters(Map<String, Object> target, Source source, Boolean defaultValue) {
    return addInternal(target, source, Boolean.parseBoolean(source.getValue()), defaultValue);
}

private Integer addIfMatters(Map<String, Object> target, Source source, Integer defaultValue) {
    return addInternal(target, source, Integer.parseInt(source.getValue()), defaultValue);
}

private <T> T addInternal(Map<String, Object> target, Source source, T converted, T defaultValue) {
    if (needed(source)) {
        target.put(source.getValue(), converted);
        return converted;
    }
    return null;
}
```